# Is there any Cordova facial recognition plugin or API to identify device Owner?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, face-id, facial-identification

I need to insure that the user who uses the application is the device owner, I already using FingerPrintAIO plugin for finger Print identification and i need to add Facial-Recognition as well.

Comment: Check this API if it helps you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/face-recognition

Comment: thank you @NajamUsSaqib for your reply, I need to clarify my question, some of smart devices have lock screen security feature with facial recognition. I need to use this feature on my application. Like AppLock application that use fingerPrint feature.

Comment: Check this also: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-lnsoft-facerecognition